# Slot numbers, pure functions

Tags: functions, pure-function, slot

For the first line of code my function works fine on the list, but when trying to use Map I just keep getting an error (Function::slotn) basically saying there are not enough arguments for it to work, why is this and how can I amend it?

```
Function[(#^#2) - #3] @@@ {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}
Map[Function[(#^#2) - #3], {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}]
```

The end result is aimed to be {-4, 1, 4093}

Comment: `@@@` is not `Map`. It is `Apply[..., {1}]`. The two lines are not equivalent. "and how can I amend it" Use Apply, not Map.

Comment: If you insist on Map, you can also use it with the operator form of Apply: `Apply[Function[(#^#2) - #3]] /@ {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}`. But somehow I don't think this is what you were after ...

Comment: There are not enough arguments because in that case the argument is a single list and `#`, `#2` etc. are not list elements, they are `Sequence` elements.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks, but yeah I was trying to use Map ideally. I'm just confused as to why it recognises #2 as the second element of each sublist in the first line, but in the second line it is seen as a single list and therefore sees it to not have a second argument?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between Map and Apply? (Check the examples on the respective reference pages.)

Comment: `(#^#2) - #3 & @@@ {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}` or 

`Apply[(#^#2) - #3 &, {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {4, 6, 3}}, 1]`